# How can I stop a character from jumping when he is grabbing something?

Tags: unity, c#

I made a feature for my game that allows the player to grab certain items when the distance between the RigidBody of the player and the object is smaller than 8, however the character is also able to jump when he is grabbing something, which is a thing that shouldn't be happening.

How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
// Code applied to floating platforms that are supposed to be grabbable, with the Y position 
// frozen and X Y rotation as well
void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void OnMouseDown() {
    distance = Vector3.Distance(character.transform.position, this.transform.position);

    // When the player grabs a object in range
    if (distance <= 8 && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.useGravity = false;
        this.transform.position = DistToPlayer.position;
        this.rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Grab").transform;
    }
}

// When the player releases the mouse button
void OnMouseUp() { 

    this.transform.parent = null;
    rb.useGravity = false;
    this.rb.constraints &= ~RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY & 
                           ~RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ & 
                           ~RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX;

}
```

Comment: Everyone loves clean code! Please take a moment to clean your code before posting it to the Internet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not an expert with Unity.*

Here is how I'd approach this:

On your character game object, add a public property `bool canJump = false;`. When you consider that the character is grabbing something, set that property to false.

Then in your update functions for your character gameobject, when a behaviour involves being able to jump or not, check the property and act accordingly.

```
if ( canJump && isFrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) )
    jump();
```

And then whenever the user releases the mouse, of course, allow the character to jump again.

---

Additionally, instead of creating a `bool canJump` as a property of your game object, you could create variables more representative of the state of the character, which would allow the controller to take better decisions.

```
bool stateIsGrabbingPlatform;
bool stateIsUnderWater;
bool stateIsGrounded;
```

This centralized approach can lead to having a lot of flags, but at least everything is where you need it.

Comment: Solved the problem just now, basically I limited the jump, if the player has the mouse0 button down he cant jump, totally fixed thanks :3

Comment: That's tying your behaviour to your input a lot. It works for now, but it'll most likely be cleaner in the long run to use specific flags instead. (Then you have to know, when you read the code, that mouse0 is being used for jumping.)